# Traffic lost by 40% but shown increasing in WMT

Tags: ranking

Around 30 days back my site lost traffic about 40%. I guess it is most likely due to algorithmic/ranking issues.

But if I see my "Search Queries" with change in the WMT I see all green and ever increasing without any red's. All the 7000 or so search keywords have infinity increase in change position. Has Google lost the historical search keyword data for my site? Here is [copy of those stats](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AraEugGV1GwTdEZtTmVJZ1JFMFJ0QmkxMWxQYVI1Ymc&usp=sharing). My site is around 3 years old.

I'm bit confused as to how to interpret it ...
[image]

Comment: whoa! are u the webmaster of irctc?

Comment: No that gets millions daily. Mine a few thousand.

Comment: "My site is around 3 years old." How long have you been registered in Google Webmaster Tools? If recent, it's possible Google's not showing you historical. If not, then I don't know.

Comment: It's registered with GWM since that time only.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect, you're seeing the result of an algorithmic change in the way Google sees your site.  You've probably lost ground on some popular keywords or phrases which accounts for the bulk of the loss but you are seeing gains on some other long-tail searches that were not previously active before the change.  This is why the infinity symbol is appearing...you went from basically unmeasured to measurable impressions/CTR on the results shown.

Sort the list the other way to see where you lost and go back in time to see the difference.

Comment: I've sorted the list other way too. It's all infinity change for all around 7000 search keywords.